# can't import more than 50 contacts from csv file to telegram using Python3

Tags: python, csv, telegram, telethon

Trying to Import 200 contacts from CSV file to telegram using Python3 Code. It's working with first 50 contacts and then stop and showing below:

telethon.errors.rpc_error_list.FloodWaitError: A wait of 101 seconds is required

Any idea how I can import all list without waiting?? Thanks!!

Comment: tl;dr you're doing too many requests. Slow down.

Comment: Just wait 101 seconds as the error description

Answer (score 0):

You can not import a large number of people in sequential. ُThe telegram finds you're sperm.

As a result, you must use ‍`sleep` between your requests